# Is it possible to clear cache of a specific function annotated with @Memoized?

Tags: groovy

I am experimenting with annotating a function with @Memoized to provide a simple caching mechanism for some data that only changes once a day.  Is it possible to instruct my application to clear the cache of a specific function?

Comment: Have you experimented using [`maxCacheSize`](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Memoized.html)?

Comment: I can see that would be useful for setting a limit on the size, but I don't see a way that I could use it for evicting all cache from a specific method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to reset the cache is to restart the application / JVM.  Looking at the code related to memoization, there doesn't seem to be anything in the API allowing a reset of the cache programatically.

The Javadoc related to memoization does mention that if garbage collection occurs, the values go away, but my guess is that is not reliable or probably even possible to force garbage collection.  http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#memoize()

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with the @Memoized annotation on a method, but you can do something similar using the .memoized() method on a closure.  Just keep a reference to the original closure and call .memoized() on it every time you want to get a new closure with a clean cache.

```
    def x = 5
    def cl = { it + x }
    def clMemo = cl.memoize()
    println clMemo(3)           //Outputs 8

    x = 1
    println clMemo(3)           //Outputs 8

    clMemo = cl.memoize()
    println clMemo(3)           //Outputs 4
```